# Trying to replace a character in string with a given character in haskell (without predefined function). for example, input 'hihi' to 'haha'

Tags: haskell

```
findReplace :: [String] -> [Char] -> [Char]-> String
findReplace [] _ _ = []
findReplace (h:t) x y
|h == x    = y : findReplace t --recursion, if the 'letter' == 'x' replace it with y 
|otherwise = h : findReplace t
```

Hi guys I'm a very new student in haskell, I was trying to to replace a character from a string with a given character, but my code is missing something that I couldn't figure out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The signature of your function is not correct, a String is already a list of chars, so you don't need the square brackets for list.
For the recursive invocation of your `findReplace` function you also need to specify all the arguments:

```
findReplace :: String -> Char -> Char -> String
findReplace [] _ _ = []
findReplace (h:t) x y
  |h == x    = y : findReplace t x y 
  |otherwise = h : findReplace t x y
```

A common pattern to avoid repeating the arguments that don't change in the recursive call, is to use a local helper function, which is often named `go`. The parameters x and y are then bound by the `findReplace` function, and can be used inside the `go` function.

```
findReplace :: String -> Char -> Char -> String
findReplace s x y = go s
  where
    go [] = []
    go (h : t)
      | h == x = y : go t
      | otherwise = h : go t
```

Comment: thanks, but what is 'go', can you explain it? :)

Comment: It's just a local function, i.e. only visible inside the findReplace function. The name `go` doesn't really matter, you can also call it differently. The advantage is that it's type is simpler: `String -> String` instead of `String -> Char -> Char -> String` and therefore the recursive invocation becomes easier. x and y which don't change for each recursive call are simply taken from the invocation of outer function `findReplace`.